# Can't insert values to database with function and always inserted even the value is null with error notification

Tags: php, mysql, function

I got problem that i cant insert the value in textbox, the value always null and always inserted even the value in textbox is null. i cant found the problem. 
code for make the class :

```
<input type="text" name="nama_kelas" value="Nama Kelas" style="width: 200px" class="input-block-level" onfocus="bersihkan(this)" onblur="kembali_semula(this)"/>
    </div>
    <div class="span3"> 
        <span id="simpan_kelas" onclick="simpan_kelas(this)" class="btn btn-success"><i class="icon-plus icon-white"></i> Kelas</span>
        <span id="update_kelas" style="display:none">
        </span>
```

save class :

```
function simpan_kelas(elm){
    var nama_kelas = $(elm).prev().val();
    if(nama_kelas != "" && nama_kelas != "nama_kelas"){
        //simpan ke database

        var data = $(elm).parent().prev();//problem disini
        var url = "simpan_form.php";
        var tabel = "kelas";
        $.post(url,{data:data,tbl:tabel},function(hasil){
            if(hasil == 1){
                // reload content dengan halaman ini
                $("#content").html(info_loading).load("daftar_kelas.php");
                }
            else{
                alert("gagal disimpan, mungkin data sudah ada \n atau koneksi bermasalah");
                }   
            })
        }
    else {
        alert("harus diisi semua....");
        }   
}
```

save form :

```
include_once "include/koneksi.php";
include_once "include/fungsi.php";
$status = 0;
$data = $_REQUEST['data'];
$tabel = $_REQUEST['tbl'];
for($i = 0; $i < count($data); $i++){
    $data_ar=$data[$i];
    foreach($data_ar as $id => $nil){
        if($id == 'value'){
        $nilai[]=mysql_escape_string($data_ar[$id]);
        }
        else 
        $nama[]=$data_ar[$id];
    }
}
$str_nilai = buatStringNilai($nilai);
$str_kolom = buatStringKolom($nama);
$sql = "insert into ".$tabel." (".$str_kolom.") values (".$str_nilai.")";
$sql_exe = mysql_query($sql);
if($sql_exe){
    $status = 1;
    }
echo $status;
```

function :

```
function buatStringNilai($data){
    $nilainya='';
    for($i = 0;$i < count($data); $i++){
            $nilainya .="'".$data[$i]."',";
            }
        $nilainya = substr($nilainya,0,strlen($nilainya) - 1);
        return $nilainya;
    }
function buatStringKolom($data){
    $nilainya='';
    for($i = 0;$i < count($data); $i++){
            $nilainya .=$data[$i].",";
            }
        $nilainya = substr($nilainya,0,strlen($nilainya) - 1);
        return $nilainya;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `save class` file, replace:

```
    var data = $(elm).parent().prev();//problem disini
```

with:

```
    var data = $("[name='nama_kelas']").val();
```

So you will get the value from the input.

`$(elm).parent()` is the wrapper for your inputs, so by doing its `prev()` you are getting the wrapper that comes before, instead of the input you want. Check the example fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/o1o7kzt6/